# Material-UI along with materialize-css

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, carousel, materialize

I'm creating an app with React , and my main styling comes from Material-UI . I want to use only one component from materialize-css which i really like (Carousel) .. I both tried implementing Carousel with M.Carousel.init method (npm installed materialize) and via jQuery as a script tag in public.html file (following instructions from materialize site ) , and both failed . Cant show my Carousel.  Trying Carousel without material-ui installed , succeeds !!

Is there an issue concerning the collaboration between these two Frameworks ?? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share an example.